# Looping through div and check if the first element is strong

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, what I am trying to do is checking if the div contains a **strong** element after (and only after) the class named *.fake-title*  . I don't want to grab all the strong elements inside the div, so in case there's no **strong** element after *.fake-title*, jQuery shouldn't do anything.

This is my code so far, unfortunately, it grabs the first **strong** element regardless of where it is placed.

HTML

```
<img src="assets/img/image_1.jpg" class="img-post">
<div class="body">
    <h1 class="fake-title"><a href=""></a></h1>

 <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> <br> Coba <strong>kalau</strong> kamu simpan ...</p>
</div>
<img src="assets/img/image_1.jpg" class="img-post">
<div class="body">
    <h1 class="fake-title"><a href=""></a></h1>
<p>What good is <strong>money</strong> if it can't inspire terror in your ..</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.body').each(function () {
 if ($('.fake-title').next('strong:first')) {
    $('.fake-title a', this).append($('strong:first', this));
    $('.fake-title a').find('strong').contents().unwrap();
 } else {
    console.log("No title found");
 }
});
```

Here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e27r8/353/).

Comment: And if it does find a strong element after a .fake-title element, what's it supposed to do?

Comment: In your example, all `<strong>` appear after a `.fake-title`

Comment: @j08691 that's showed in the fiddle.

Comment: @SetSailMedia yes, but in the second example, it's not immediately followed by the .fake-title, it just picks the first strong element it finds and use it as title, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.body').each(function () {
    if ($('.fake-title').next('strong:first')) {
        $('.fake-title a', this).append($('strong:first', this));
        $('.fake-title a').find('strong').each(function() {
            $(this)..contents().unwrap();
        });


    } else {
        console.log("No title found");
    }
});

$('.body').each(function () {
    if ($('.fake-title').next('strong:first')) {
        $('.fake-title a', this).append($('strong:first', this));
        $('.fake-title a').find('strong').each(function() {
            $(this).unwrap();
        });


    } else {
        console.log("No title found");
    }
});
```

Its help?